# what is <spring:message>?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What is `<spring:message>` tag?What is its use?
I tried to Google it but could not find any useful content.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the text According to the language using Those Tags. Simply using

```
<spring:message code="some_name"/>
```

tag you can populate the text into your JSP using relevant .properties file after configured it.

For Tutorial you can use below link

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Answer (score 0):

It is used during internationalization, Google is full of tutorials... One of them: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/